# Express as a fourier series or another series for a function

Tags: sequences-and-series, improper-integrals, fourier-series

there is Someone asked me a question on a social media ,
And the question  was how to represent $\ln^2\left |  \cot \left ( \frac{\Theta x}{2} -\frac{\pi}{4}\right )\right | $  as a series  where $\Theta >0 $.
When I saw this function I remembered the inverse gudermanian function.
And I represented it as a fourier series,  which it is $4\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ \sin\left ( \frac{n \pi}{2} \right ) \sin\left ( n \Theta x \right )} n =\ln(\cot\left | \frac{\Theta x } 2 -\frac{\pi}{4} \right |)$ then , I tried to express $\ln^2$.
I got $16\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin^2 \left ( \frac{n \pi}{2} \right ) \sin^2(n \Theta x)}{n^2}$,
But I think the second one is wrong but why? I don't know this all what I can do.
 I'm looking for any help and I will be hopeful for mathstack team's help

Comment: Please review your question for orthographical and punctuation errors. Also think about reformatting it for readability.

Comment: Okay m. Winter I will

Comment: Can I know why the downvote?

Comment: I edit the question as I can ,,,any thing to do else?

Comment: As I said, punctuation. It is hard to read.

Comment: I put a punctuation